# What kind of phrase is this? (adverb and adjective at the beginning of a sentence)

Tags: grammaticality

I just encountered this sentence in a passage, which begins with an adverb and adjective.

> Probably blind from birth, he was born into a noble family...

*'Probably blind from birth'* - What kind of phrase is this?

Comment: Adjectival phrase modifying the subject pronoun *he*.

Comment: It's an absolute construction.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction .

Comment: 'It' is (2) an absolute phrase coming after (1) a pragmatic marker (modal: giving the speaker's assessment of the likelihood of the accuracy of the statement), traditionally known as a sentence adverbial.

Comment: It doesn't seem to modify the entire sentence, but only "he".  It really doesn't follow the examples of an absolute construction.

Comment: It's not an absolute construction. An absolute is a clause with a subject-predicate structure, but your example is just an adjective phrase. It's best analysed as a predicative adjunct: predicative in that it relates to a predicand, i.e. "he", and an adjunct because it is a optional item in clause structure. Compare the predicative complement equivalent "He was probably blind from birth".